# AngularJs - Use custom filter inside directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

**Scenario** 
I have an array of users containing information about them, I do an `ng-repeat` combined with a custom directive that generates an HTML user card, keeping the scope of each card relative to the individual user, inside the user model there is a value that I need to filter with a custom filter before the template gets compiled, because if I do it inside the template the time it takes to be filtered makes the tooltip not to show until the value is ready and that looks as if something is not working.

**My code so far**

```
// userCard directive
angular.module('userCard', []).directive('UserCard', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    templateUrl: 'userCard.tpl.html',
    scope: {
        user: '='
    },
    controller: ['$scope', 'fromNowFilter', function($scope, fromNowFilter) {

        angular.forEach($scope.user.reminders, function(reminder) {
            reminder.last_sent = reminder.last_sent === null ? 'No reminder has been sent!' : fromNowFilter(reminder.last_sent);
        });
    }],
    link: function(scope, element) {
        // Add the base class to the user card element
        element.addClass('user-card');
    }
  };
});


// fromNow custom filter
angular.module('userCard').filter('fromNow', function() {
  return function(date) {
    return moment(date).fromNow();
  };
});


// The error I keep getting
Unknown provider: fromNowFilterProvider <- fromNowFilter
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try inject [filterprovider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$filterProvider) and run your filter.

```
controller: ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
       var fromNowFilter = $filter('fromNow');
        angular.forEach($scope.user.reminders, function(reminder) {
            reminder.last_sent = reminder.last_sent === null ? 'No reminder has been sent!' : fromNowFilter(reminder.last_sent);
        });
    }],
```

Comment: Just tried that but still getting the same error, I am trying to follow the Angular [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter), what I understand is that you need to postfix your filter name with `Filter` to inject it.

Comment: @CupOfJoe Yeah that should have worked as well.. Are you sure you have loaded the scipt for the filter in your app?

Comment: Yes, I tested it inside the template and it works, but cant' get it to inject inside the directives controller.

Comment: @CupOfJoe It works for me.. See this demo. http://plnkr.co/edit/0jhiqM?p=preview Which version of angular you are using?

Comment: I am using `angular 1.3.0-beta.19` I will give it one more try following your plunker and let you know what happens. Thanks!

Comment: @CupOfJoe It works with that as well.http://plnkr.co/edit/Ry3C1m?p=preview Are you sure the code you have posted is exactly the way you are using it?

Comment: I owe you a huge apology, thank you for all your help, I started checking everything after seeing your examples, and the problem was, that I use CodeKit to compile files, and when I created the filter I did not add it to the prepends list in the main JS file. Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem. It happens.. Hence my first comment itself, i asked that.. :)

Comment: it should be like **var fromNowFilter = $filter('fromNow');** not  *var fromNowFilter = $filter('fromNowFilter ');*  we don't want to concatenate *filter*