# How to include a filter in a custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm new to Angular JS and am having trouble with custom directives. I've tried to copy a tutorial and I can't get it working using my own code.
Here's the relevant part of my HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="calcController" class="container">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="balInput">Balance:</label>
<input id="balInput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="balance" ng-change="updateAnnualInt(balance)" placeholder="Please enter your balance here...">
</div> 
<p>{{'At a '+(interestRate)+'% interest rate you would save...'}}</p>
<p style="text-indent: 30px;" ng-repeat="interest in interests">{{'per '+interest.time+': '}}{{(interest.factor*annualInterest*0.01) | currency:'£'}}</p>
```

To start with, I'm just trying to turn the last paragraph into a custom directive. Here's my attempt:

```
app.directive('interest-amount',function(){
var directive={};
directive.restrict='E';
directive.template="<p style='text-indent: 30px;'>'per '+{{interest.time}}+': '{{(interest.factor*annualInterest*0.01) | currency:'£'}}</p>";

directive.compile=function(element,attributes){
    var linkFunction=function($scope, element,attributes){
        element.html("<p style='text-indent: 30px;'>per "+$scope.interest.time+": "+($scope.interest.factor*$scope.annualInterest*0.01)+"</p>");    
    }
    return linkFunction;
}
return directive;
})
```

This isn't giving the HTML template I expect when I insert it as follows:

```
<interest-amount ng-repeat="interest in interests"></interest-amount>
```

My first question is why is this not working?

I am also confused as to how to include the currency filter in the `linkFunction`. What is the syntax for encoding this in Javascript rather than Angular-powered HTML?

Thanks

Comment: does it have to be done in the link function? You could have a much easier time doing a lot of the operations in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your first question, the directive should be declared in camel case. So, declare the directive like this :

```
app.directive('interestAmount',function(){
```

And call it the way you are doing currently.

```
<interest-amount ng-repeat="interest in interests"></interest-amount>
```

This should take you inside the directive code.

For your second question, you should use a directive controller. Just create a controller for this directive, inject $filter in that controller and call function of that controller from link function of your directive.
Refer this : [AngularJs - Use custom filter inside directive controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25560248/angularjs-use-custom-filter-inside-directive-controller)

Answer (score 0):

```
app.directive('interestAmount',function($filter){ // camel case, as @isha aggarwal noted
    $filter('filterName')('argument');
});
```